# How to create endpoint with different response content types depending on accept header in Java with Micronaut

Tags: java, web-services, content-type, endpoint, micronaut

I am having a play with Micronaut, and want to create an endpoint that returns either `text/plain` or `text/html`, depending on the Accept header in the request.

I found two ways to do this:

1. create two methods for the same endpoint with different *produces* attributes,
2. handle it all in a single method and that evaluates the accept header and use logic in my own code to return the right content type.

I like the first way best, because it's very clean, and requires no logic from me:

```
    @Get(uri="/", produces="text/html")
    public String indexHtml() {
        return """
            <html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head>
            <body>
            <h1>Demo service</h1>
            </body></html>""";
    }
    @Get(uri="/", produces="text/plain")
    public String indexText() {
        return "Demo service\r\n";
    }
```

This works well when an accept header is in the request. However, when there is no accept header, I get an error response `400 Bad Request` with a message `"More than 1 route matched the incoming request. The following routes matched /demo: GET - /demo, GET - /demo"`

**Question 1**
Is there a way to provide a 3rd endpoint as a fallback, or to designate one of these methods as the default?

The second way to do it, resulted in a method that I don't find very elegant:

```
    @Get(uri="/", produces={MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
    public String index(HttpRequest<?> request) {
        Collection<MediaType> mediaTypes = request.accept();
        Iterator<MediaType> it = mediaTypes.iterator();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            MediaType mediaType = it.next();
            if (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE.equals(mediaType))
                    return "Demo service\r\n";
            if (MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE.equals(mediaType))
                    return """
                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head>
                        <body>
                        <h1>Demo service</h1>
                        </body></html>""";
        }
        return """
            {
                "title": "Demo service",
            }""";
    }
```

**Question 2**

- If it's really necessary to handle this in a single method, is it indeed done by fetching the accept header and evaluating that, or should it be done differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Get(produces="*/*")` to provide a fallback-like endpoint that will be executed when the `Accept` header is missing for the endpoints that use the same URI and are controlled by the specific content type. Take a look at the example below:

```java
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.QueryValue;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @Get(produces = "application/json")
    Map<?,?> helloJson(@QueryValue(defaultValue = "unknown") String name) {
        return Map.of("message", "Hello, " + name + "!");
    }

    @Get(produces = "text/plain")
    String helloText(@QueryValue(defaultValue = "unknown") String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }

    @Get(produces = "*/*")
    String helloDefault(@QueryValue(defaultValue = "unknown") String name) {
        return helloText(name) + " (from default endpoint)";
    }
}
```

And here is what happens when we call this controller with and without the `Accept` header:

```bash
$ curl -H "Accept:application/json" "localhost:8080/hello?name=test"
{"message":"Hello, test!"}%

$ curl -H "Accept:text/plain" "localhost:8080/hello?name=test"
Hello, test%

$ curl "localhost:8080/hello?name=test"                             
Hello, test (from default endpoint)%
```

Comment: PS: I shared a similar example in the themnfiles.com series some time ago - https://twitter.com/wololock/status/1547120883910807553 You may want to check them out for a bite-sized Micronaut related tips and tricks. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for this. When I try this, it does get me one step closer to what I want, because the default is chosen when there's an accept header that is not explicitly handled, e.g., "Accept:text/html" takes me to the default endpoint.
But when there is no Accept header, I still get the "More than 1 route..."  error.
I think curl has a default Accept header with "Accept: \*/\*".

Comment: Yes, you are right - curl by default adds `Accept: */*` which can be found when we run `curl -v ...`. I researched the `Accept` header definition and I found this in the RFC document - `If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types.` (source: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#:~:text=If%20no%20Accept%20header%20field,406%20(not%20acceptable)%20response.) So it looks like Micronaut behaves as expected in the case of a missing `Accept` header.